# Is there a way to send video files downloaded via wget directly to dropbox, without having to store each one on my computer's storage?

Tags: python, video, wget, dropbox

I'm using wget to download a video file from a given source. Then sending them, after they are downloaded to my computer's storage, to a dropbox folder via their api. I want to avoid storing a large quantity of videos temporarily to my computer.

`wget.download(url, out = local_path)`

I'm thinking there may be a way to specify the dropbox location instead of local path or something similar.

I would really appreciate any help! Let me know if there is anything else I can provide or clear up!

Comment: See [Programmatically saving a URL to Dropbox](https://dropbox.tech/developers/programmatically-saving-a-url-to-dropbox) and [dropbox.dropbox_client.Dropbox.files_save_url](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox_client.Dropbox.files_save_url).